# AWS ENI attachment commands not working from metadata

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, network-interface

I'm trying to attach a secondary eni while launching a windows server 2012 r2 ec2 instance, I have added the below commands in the userdata.pl, which is calling from a terraform asg resource creation script.
The commands are working fine inside the windows machine powershell console, but not working though the userdata. Unfortunatly I couldn't see any error in the logs for this.. it's just continuing with the other execution parts. Need you inputs to fix this issue, please let me know if any of you have gone though the same kind of issue in your past experience?

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("man_proxy", 'http://man-proxy.com:80', "Machine")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("http_proxy", 'http://man-proxy.com:80', "Machine")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("https_proxy", 'http://man-proxy.com:80', "Machine")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("no_proxy", '199.111.111.111,.xxxxx.com,.xxxxxx.com,.xxxxxx.com,.xxxx.com', "Machine")
cmd.exe /c "aws ec2 attach-network-interface --region $region --network-interface-id ${eni_id} --instance-id $instanceId --device-index 1"
```

Comment: Have you injected debug statements (the equivalent of echo) into the userdata script before and after the attempt to attach the ENI? Have you echoed the actual values of $region, $instanceId etc. to check they are correct? Why are you using ${eni_id} but $instanceId?

Comment: Yes, region and eni_id values are getting, I could see that in log.
the debug values are printing, but, eni is not attaching, not seeing any failure also.